# How to get file from root server dir

Tags: html, codeigniter-4

this is my dir

- data-ujipetikjf/upload/pendahuluan/this_is_myfile
- var/www/html/index.php (my index CI)
- var/www/html/ci4/app/view....

data-ujipetikjf equals position with var

this is my html

```
<iframe src="../../../../data-ujipetikjf/upload/pendahuluan/this_is_myfile#toolbar=0" style="height:100%;width:100%" title="Iframe Example">
</iframe>
```

and this is what i got:

[image]

Comment: You have no right to access the file. Check the permissions on the folder/file and make sure the server can read files from outside `/var/www`

Comment: Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/q/357108)

Comment: now my error is "404 file not found". is the path wrong?